# vim: Prevent :exe from quitting after error

Tags: vim, vi, ex

I have an error-checking one-liner vim command that looks like the following. It's not directly part of the question but works as an example, so feel free to ignore it:

```
:'<,'>g/foo{.*}/exe "norm! mxf{lvt}y/\\(foo{\\)\\@!\<C-R>\"\<enter>yy'xP"
```

Here is an explanation:

- `:'<,'>g/foo{.*}/` - Run the following command on all highlighted lines with `foo{...}`
- `exe "norm!` - Start executing normal mode commands on each line
- `mx` - Record the current line
- `f{lvt}y` - Copy everything inside the curly braces of `foo{...}`
- `/\\(foo{\\)\\@!\<C-R>\"\<enter>` - Forward search to an instance where the string inside the curly braces of `foo{...}` is **not** inside `foo`
- `yy'xP"` - Copy that line, go back to `x`, and paste it above.

This is basically an error-checking command to see that every time a term is wrapped by `foo{`, it is **always** wrapped by foo. However, `exe` exits on the first case where `/` (forward search) doesn't find anything. I don't want that to happen.

**How do I make `exe`and `:g` continue even with errors inside the `exe` command?** I have tried `:silent`, but that does not save it.

I'd rather keep this as a one-liner, but functions are a second option I am okay with.

Comment: You don't seem to even need `:execute` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @romainl, do you know how I could do this without `:exe`? I am lost...

Comment: Just `normal! ...`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that won't work for me because it's hard to type some control keys through an ssh connection (so `:exe` is useful for me to type "\<enter>"). I tested the normal mode one just now on my local machine and it does work, though, so thanks: `:'<,'>norm! mxf{lvt}"ay/\(foo{\)\@!^R"a^Myy'xP` - the `^R` and `^M` are `<C-R>` and `<Enter>`, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:silent` alone is not enough. You need to use `:silent!`. From `:help :silent` (emphasis mine):

> When [!] is added, error messages will also be
>   skipped, and **commands and mappings will not be aborted
>   when an error is detected**.

Comment: Thanks, that got it!